# How do i send a input type file as a binary?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I simply want to get my HTML file input as a binary to save it in my SQL SERVER. The code below,apparently solves my problem,but i can't get "`reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0])`" and store in a variable.
It just `console.log` the  `input.files[0]` ,but i need to store it.
Also,I'm not used to `FileReader()`,so any tips on how to use it are welcome.

Does this function uses the actual file being uploaded,or does it get the path to it?

The code is simple:

```
<input type="file"  id="myFile" name="myFile">
```

JS:

```
$("#myFile").change(function (event) {
  var input = event.target;
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function () {
    console.log(reader.result);
  };
  fileToSave = reader.readAsBinaryString(input.files[0]);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`readAsBinaryString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) doesn't return anything.  What it does do is tell the `FileReader` to begin reading the file.  *When that process finishes*, you can see the data you're reading in the `result` property of the `FileReader` object.

Which you've observed is available in the `onload` event:

```
reader.onload = function(){
    console.log(reader.result);
};
```

Since that event is when the data is available, then that event is where you can read that data.  For example:

```
reader.onload = function(){
    fileToSave = reader.result;
    console.log(fileToSave);
};
```

Of course then the next question becomes... When/where do you attempt to *use* the value in `fileToSave`.  Keep in mind that this is an asynchronous operation.  If you're trying to use the data in `fileToSave` right away then of course it won't contain the data that is later available in this `onload` event.

Whatever operation needs to use that data, that operation would have to happen after this event.  For example:

```
reader.onload = function(){
    fileToSave = reader.result;
    console.log(fileToSave);
    someOtherOperation();
};
```

or perhaps even:

```
reader.onload = function(){
    const fileToSave = reader.result;
    console.log(fileToSave);
    someOtherOperation(fileToSave);
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You explanation made everything clearer to me. So *after* I receive the data on onload,i could send it trough an $.ajax or something like that?

Comment: @Master: Correct.  And there are a variety of ways you can structure that, but as long as you ensure that you're performing operations after the data is available then that should work.

Comment: Thank you so much. Can i make one more question? Does FileReader get the actual image uploaded or it gets the path of the image from the user PC? Do you know anything about that?

Comment: @Master: Given that you've observed it successfully logging the file's binary data to the console, I'd conclude that it reads the actual file.  The path would be of little use once the file itself has been read, and certainly of no use to the server.  What you're doing with that binary data, client-side or server-side, is potentially another issue entirely.

Comment: Okay,thanks for the answers,you helped me more than you can imagine. I can't seem to find much info about FileReader on the web,don't know why. Thanks!!!!!!!!